# How will you unit test a function containing hash table data type?

Tags: unit-testing

My project generates a few values (equal partitioning method) for each data type by getting the minimum and maximum values.  I am generating these values for functional testing, I am actually passing these values to nunit partner, max and min are applicable to int, float, double etc. These values are test data.

Initially I generated them for basic data types like int, float, double, string etc.

Now I need to support data types like DataSet, HashTable and other Collections.

```
public DataSet MySampleMethod(int param1, string param2, Hashtable ht)
```

For testing this function I can pass values for int and string, but how will I pass test data for `ht` or how is test data generated for a hash table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to abstract the hash table implementation out of the code so that it can be mocked, injected or stubbed when unit testing.

Just create an interface called IHashTable and then create your concrete implementation by implementing the interface. Then make all your classes that use hashtables now use IHashTable. Then add a parameter to their constructors to which accepts an IHashTable.

Then when you're unit testing pass in a mock or stub of the IHashTable interface.

Mocking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Comment: is there any open source tool for creating stubs

Comment: any you suggest some examples for the above answer

Comment: an u give example for the above answer

Comment: The original post does not imply that HashTable has to be mocked. I read it that the poster needs to have certain data pre-loaded into it.  So, simply construct a HashTable instance, populate it and pass it in.